# D-Link DIR-615 bricked. Power led stays orange, can't get into emergency flash mode

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

After changing some Wireless settings on my D-Link DIR-615 with custom flashed DD-WRT I might have unplugged the power cord too soon. When I plugged in again it didn't seem to boot. Just an orange power led and orange internet globe led. After plugging it again to my computer to check what's wrong only the power led turns on orange.

[image: Power led stays orange]

I've been trying all sorts of things like the 30/30/30 trick, tried to get it in emergency flash mode but none of those seem to have effect on it. The power led stays orange and it doesn't broadcast a Wireless signal and it doesn't turn on LAN, I can't discover it on both WLAN or LAN.

Any help appreciated!

--

Some more information about the Router itself:
[image: Router information]

Comment: Does the router have a TTL or JTAG port?

Comment: @Ramhound: It doesn't have a JTAG port but it does have some serial pins. I tried soldering cables to the serial pins and read the output using a Raspberry Pi but it doesn't show anything.. http://i.imgur.com/sEhHDk7.jpg

So I closed it back up and I'm back to the orange power led that just stays on.

Answer (score 1):

Hold in reset, power up. keep holding in reset until power light flashes on/off. It can take up to 30 seconds. Set your computer to static ip 192.168.0.10/255.255.255.0 & DNS 192.168.0.1 - Assuming you have windows, Plugin LAN cable between computer and router, open internet explorer and go to http://192.168.0.1 - You should see the emergency firmware upload page. If you don't, you need to use JTAG, which involves making the cable and soldering on connections. Easier to get another DIR-615.

Comment: That's the emergency flash mode which I can't get in. Normally the power led should start blinking but it never does. It just stays orange. Neither my MacBook or my desktop PC can detect the router (and yes, the static IP is configured correctly).

Comment: Does any LAN port light up when you connect a cable between it and your computer?

Comment: No, they don't. Tried all of them.

Comment: Write the obituary :(